# gstreamer playbin on Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, gstreamer

I am simply trying to play video with gstreamer on a Raspberry Pi Model 3B+ running Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit. ffplay and vlc work fine, but gstreamer doesn't. The command and output are:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:~/Downloads/sample_640x360.mp4
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Redistribute latency...
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstKMSSink:kmssink0: GStreamer encountered a general resource error.
Additional debug info:
../sys/kms/gstkmssink.c(1711): gst_kms_sink_show_frame (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstKMSSink:kmssink0:
drmModeSetPlane failed: Permission denied (13)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst/isomp4/qtdemux.c(6545): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Freeing pipeline ...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Even gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink doesn't work, however gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! ximagesink does.

Comment: From the error message, it is trying to render to a `kmssink` (direct rendering to a DRM device), but it got a permission denied error trying to configure the DRM mode.  What happens if you add your user to the "videos" group?  That might grant it access to the DRM device.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/pi/Downloads/sample_640x360.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideoconvert ! ximagesink
```

The following also works, but is very slow/jerky:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/pi/Downloads/sample_640x360.mp4 video-sink=ximagesink
```

Still not sure why autovideosink is not working.